# The Magnus affect and charge, angular momentum and the electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

In the [Magnus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect), a rotating body undergoes deflection along its direction of travel under the turbulence created by its interaction with air. Similarly, a charged particle with linear and angular momentum will undergo deflection in an electromagnetic field.

Is the Magnus effect a helpful analogy for thinking about the interaction between charge, angular momentum and the electromagnetic field, or is it a misleading one?

Comment: Eric, you are right. See my elaboration https://www.academia.edu/12037987/About_the_internal_cause_of_Lorentz_force_electric_and_magnetic_induction_English_Deutsch_